# Merge objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects and I want to merge them, but it should not replace the object.

```
var x = {'one':1, 'two': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}
var y = {'two': {'b': 4}}
```

When I merge them The out put should be :

```
{'one':1, 'two': {'b': 4, 'c': 3}}
```

Comment: [There are no such things as JSON objects](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) those are just plain JS Objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursive approach for updating nested object.

```js
var x = {
  'one': 1,
  'two': {
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
  }
}
var y = {
  'two': {
    'b': 4
  }
}


function merge(a, b) {
// create new object and copy the properties of first one
  var res = Object.assign({}, a);
  //iterate over the keys of second object
  Object.keys(b).forEach(function(e) {
    // check key is present in first object
    // check type of both value is object(not array) and then
    // recursively call the function
    if (e in res && typeof res[e] == 'object' && typeof res[e] == 'object' && !(Array.isArray(res[e]) || Array.isArray(b[e]))) {
   // recursively call the function and update the value 
   // with the returned ne object
   res[e] = merge(res[e], b[e]);
    } else {
      // otherwise define the preperty directly
      res[e] = b[e];
    }
  });
  return res;
}

var res = merge(x, y);

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to merge the array then you need to do something like this.

```js
var x = {
  'one': 1,
  'two': {
    'b': [22, 23],
    'c': 3
  }
}
var y = {
  'two': {
    'b': [24]
  }
}


function merge(a, b) {
  var res = Object.assign({}, a);
  Object.keys(b).forEach(function(e) {
    if (e in res && typeof res[e] == 'object' && typeof res[e] == 'object' && !(Array.isArray(res[e]) || Array.isArray(b[e]))) {
      res[e] = merge(res[e], b[e]);
      // in case both values are array 
    } else if (Array.isArray(res[e]) && Array.isArray(b[e])) {
      // push the values in second object
      [].push.apply(res[e], b[e]);
      // or use 
      // res[e] = res[e].concat(b[e]);
    } else {
      res[e] = b[e];
    }
  });
  return res;
}

var res = merge(x, y);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You should also protect the array case, as arrays are considered objects in JS.

Comment: @MisterJ array would be updated based on index

Comment: which would lead to case that don't make sense most of the times (cf this example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oejobe?editors=1111 )

Comment: @MisterJ : yes, but it depends on the expected behaviour

Comment: @MisterJ : in case we need to avoid happening that, then add `Array.isArray(....)` in the condition

Comment: @MisterJ : something like `if (e in a && typeof a[e] == 'object' && typeof b[e] == 'object' && !(Array.isArray(a[e]) || Array.isArray(b[e])))`

Comment: yup, technically !Array.isArray(a[e]) && !Array.isArray(b[e]). But I don't see any case where you might actually want an array to be merged in the object. Even though we agree, it would not lead to a crash.

Comment: @MisterJ : that's right I will update ;)

Comment: And last point, your answer is actually updating a in place, user was asking for a version which would not replace in place, so you should start by doing a copy of a , and then replacing doing the same job as you are doing in the copy of a.

Comment: @MisterJ : ok i will update

Comment: @MisterJ : done :)

Comment: In case of array it should also be merged, It should not het replaced.

ex. x.two = [11,22], y.two = [33]

Output should be [11,22,33]    not    [33]

Comment: @KRUSHANUMOHAPATRA : updated

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks :)
I have user _.js

else {
            // otherwise define the preperty directly
            if ((Array.isArray(res[e]) && Array.isArray(b[e]))) {
                res[e] = _.union(res[e], b[e]);
            } else {
                res[e] = b[e];
            }
        }

Comment: @KRUSHANUMOHAPATRA : you can use concat method.... Check the commented line